# When a notification feed unfollows a flat feed, are activities removed?

Tags: getstream-io

The title pretty much says it all, but I'll repeat in the body with more detail.

When notification feed `notification:user1` follows flat feed `posts:user2`, activities are copied from `posts:user2` to `notification:user1`. The precise number of activities to be copied can be optionally specified by passing an `activityCopyLimit` integer.

However, when a feed unfollows another feed, there is no similar option to control  this behavior. The documentation simply states:

> Existing activities in the feed coming from the target feed will be purged (asynchronously)

So my question is: is this *also* the case when it comes to notification feeds?

Whether it is or not, the option to **not** purge activities would be very useful. Just because a user no longer needs to receive activities from a given feed doesn't necessarily mean that the history of what has been received should disappear.

Thanks much.

Comment: @Matthisk looks more like an answer than a comment ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to not purge the history when unfollowing feeds using the `keep_history` parameter. This feature is still not available on all official clients but it is described in the [API rest documentation](https://getstream.io/docs_rest/#following_detail). The parameter needs to be provided as part of the query parameters and have value `true` or `1`. If your client is not yet supported, you should open a ticket on its [Github repository](https://github.com/getstream/?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=stream-).

Comment: Looks like you guys added it to the `stream-js` repo a few days ago and bumped the version to 3.2.0. Could you please update stream-meteor to use 3.2.0? I'll request in github as well.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not possible, the feed will always be purged. I do understand your use case and we will consider adding this feature to our roadmap.